# How to show mat-table in Expanded Mat-row rather than in Main table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have a mat-table with expanded rows. If I click on a row it expands and shows hardcoded text.
For now, I am able to display a mat-table with expanded rows. From API I am getting the following details:-

1. Job Id
2. Execution Id
3. Before Time Period
4. After Time Period
5. Status

I just want to display Before and After Time Period on Mat-row and if I click on row it should expand and I should be able to view rest of the details.
How can I achieve this?
For now I am able to display whole data on main row and on clicking on the row it expands and I am able to show a hardcoded string 'This is expanded row'.
I tried to make my mat-expanded row table by referencing the code in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows)

Comment: I am confused so you want to show a table in a table? Or a mat list when expanded that gives you a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a table in table. Which is called a detail table here is a good guide on how to do it

https://www.dzurico.com/angular-master-detail-table/

Answer (score 1):

Please find below an example where I display a table inside another table, for each line that can be extended
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nyyadr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

in your example, you can change the data sources and the columns to be displayed.

```
 displayedColumns: string[] = ['BeforeTimePeriod', 'AfterTime Period'];
 displayedColumns2: string[] = ['JobId', 'ExecutionId', 'Status'];

 don't forget to modify the loading of data after the click in the toggleRow(item) function.
```

Don't hesitate to give me a data set and I'll do it for your use case, if needed.